# GC overhead limit exceeded (Spark Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, out-of-memory

I am getting the error GC overhead limit exceeded using Intellij with a process made in Scala Spark as you can see in the following image:

[Error GC overhead limit exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQEwD.png)

I have been searching a solution for this error here and another sites but the error is still on.
This is my settigs:

Scala Compiler:

[Settings Scala Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXzON.png)

Intellij Compiler:

[Intellij Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjfpK.png)

What can I have wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: I don't see how the compiler settings are relevant here, since the exception occurs when *running* your code, not when compiling it. Also [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You have to increase the memory of your spark executors. Perhaps also of your Spark driver process. Better partitioning of your RDD or dataframe could also help.